# hadoop-namenode host login issue

Tags: java, logging, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, host

Hello, here i have problem in login into hadoop-namenode host. When i login into hadoop-namenode host, login is done successfully but my working host(bycb4y1) does not change. So i can't format the namenode on cluster

```
hduser1@bycb4y1:/$ ssh  hadoop-namenode
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Mon Aug  5 17:05:47 2013 from 192.168.41.53
hduser1@bycb4y1:~$
```

Comment: Cannot get your wordings. Can you share some details about your problem?

Comment: my host is not change into hadoop-namenode after successful login into hadoop-namenode

Comment: Could you please show me your **/etc/hosts** file?

Comment: hello Tariq 
 this is my hosts file
hduser1@bycb4y1:~$ cat /etc/hosts
192.168.41.53    hadoop-namenode
192.168.41.87    hadoop-datanode1
192.168.41.67    hadoop-datanode2
127.0.0.1 localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
hduser1@bycb4y1:~$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats your problem is; I guess some thing related to permission issue; Try running Sudo su or follow http://www.sudo.ws/.

Comment: If there was some permission related problem, login itself was not possible, IMHO.